# Android view with many different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a home screen for an Android app. The homescreen will be a vertically scrolling list, containing many different elements.

These elements can be things such as a simple card list, a side scrolling carousel of items (`ViewPager`?) or just a basic `WebView`.

Is it possible to use a `RecyclerView` efficiently with multiple types of content (that can also have their own adapters). Or is there something else available that I may not be aware of?

The BBC news app is similar close to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` is actually designed to do such things, I don't think that you have any other choices right here, however this shouldn't cause you any problems I've tried something like this earlier last month and it worked perfectly for me 
even tho i added multiple types of content, the only problem that i faced was with the `ListView` because i added some sort of animation to the content 
but after i used a `recyclerView` everything worked fine but you also have to reconsider using a `ViewPager` inside a `RecyclerView` as an Item, it might cause you some problems as it should be used in conjunction with `Fragment` to allow users to flip left and right through pages of data which in most of the cases are tabs.

[checkout the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

And the BBC news app that you refer to in your question is using a `RecyclerView` inside a tab into a `TabHost` that uses `ViewPager`.

[More Information About `RecyclerView`.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Good Example for RecyclerView  [Sample for RecyclerView](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/)